# Duplicate title tags in Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console

Under *Google Webmaster Tools > HTML Improvements > Duplicate title tags*

I can see 800 duplicates listed. They are not exact duplicates but rather pages as shown below:

```
/questions/0?page=1058&sort=asc&order=Solution
/questions/0?page=1080
/questions/0?page=1194
/questions/0?page=1350&sort=desc&order=Category
/questions/0?page=1405&sort=desc&order=Reads
/questions/0?page=1597&sort=asc&order=Author
/questions/0?page=1609&sort=asc&order=Category
/questions/0?page=168&sort=desc&order=Reads
/questions/0?page=1683&sort=asc&order=Reads
/questions/0?page=1962&sort=asc&order=Posted%20date
/questions/0?page=2131&sort=asc&order=Author
/questions/0?page=2132&sort=asc&order=Author
/questions/0?page=334&sort=desc&order=Node%20Nid
```

How can I fix them and not have them displayed in Google Webmaster Tools as duplicates, since they are different pages?

Comment: Open the HTML (open link -> view page source) and check what is between <title> and </title>. Is it the same? make sure you change the code to make each different.

Answer (score 2):

It appears from your question (if I edited it correctly) that Google Webmaster Tools is indicating you have duplicate title tags for multiple pages.

If you want to fix these errors, you'd have to supply a different title for each page. See this for more on that:  [Google Webmaster Tools - Site title](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=en).

Alternatively, you can chose to block these pages from being indexed by using the following meta tag in them, as covered here: [Google Webmaster Tools - Using meta tags to prevent robots from indexing a page on your site](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en).

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

Or you can block the entire `/questions/` directory from being crawled by adding this to your [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /questions/
```